# Convert Y-m-d H:M:S format to int in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, strptime

Using pandas, I made my csv file into dataframe and named it as `data_A`

```
data_A = pd.read_csv("D:/power.csv")
```

`data_A` has the column `time`

[image: time column]

I want to convert it to integer type.
For example, `2020-01-01 00:00:00` to `20200101000000`
The data type of `data_A['time']` is object.
How can I change the whole column time into int64 values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most consistent way (that protects against incidentally odd dates) is to convert the column to datetimes and then to strings:

```
pd.to_datetime(data_A.time).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S').astype(int)
#0    20200101000000
#1    20200101000020
#Name: time, dtype: int64
```

But since your `time` is essentially strings, you can split them by punctuation and then join:

```
data_A.time.str.split('\W').str.join('').astype(int)
#0    20200101000000
#1    20200101000020
#Name: time, dtype: int64
```

The second solution is about 40% faster.

Comment: The second solution works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Lee: if this answers solves your question, consider [accepting it as solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Both solutions work.